# How to access Kubernetes service from local network

Tags: kubernetes

I currently use a SOCKS proxy to access `10.64.140.43.nip.io` from my laptop. My Kubernetes service is hosted on a server with static IP address `192.168.0.29` on the same network as my laptop. How do I access the Kubernetes service without the SOCKS proxy by directly going to `192.168.0.29`?

Here's the output from `kubectl get services | grep 10.64.140.43`:

`kubeflow istio-ingressgateway-workload  LoadBalancer 10.152.183.47  10.64.140.43  80:32696/TCP,443:31536/TCP  24h`

Answer (score -1):

Try using a NodePort Service instead of a LoadBalancer, or use something like [klipper-lb](https://github.com/k3s-io/klipper-lb)